# Javascript: shift a bidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, buffer

I created an array of samples in the following way:

```
var data = new Array(8);
...
data[n].push([x, y]);
```

where n is the channel (0-7) and [x, y] the current sample of the selected channel.
For a particular application I need to leave x values untouched (0, 1, 2, 3, ... m) and shift the y values each time I get a new sample.

A simple example with m = 3. After the first load I have:

```
data[0] -> [0, 2] [1, 4] [2, 6]
```

when a new sample is received I want to change the array like this:

```
data[0] -> [0, 4] [1, 6] [2, 8]
```

Because m could have values up to 5000 I'm wondering which is the best way to do this.
Of course I can cycle the whole array changing the y value of position j to the y value of position j+1.

Is there something better?
Thanks!

Comment: Read a couple times, don't get it... Do you have some code? That'll make it easier to understand.

Comment: Currently I'm looking for the best solution. I haven't write yet much code. What do you not understand? I apologize for my English, I'm aware I cannot explain very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to change every item in array without explicit cycle.

```
var data = [
        [0,2], [1,4], [2,6]
    ];

function update(data) {
    data.map(function(item,key) {
        if(key+1>data.length-1) return;
        data[key][1] = data[key+1][1];
    });
    // if we shift, the last item Y should have empty value
    data[data.length-1][1] = undefined;
}

update(data);

console.log(data); // [0,4], [1,6], [2,undefined]
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yZwX/2/).

You may also like this black magic inspired by @rab's solution in the comment

```
var data = [ [0,2], [1,4], [2,6] ];
data.map(function(_,i,o){o[i][1]=o[++i]&&o[i][1]});
console.log(data); // [0,4], [1,6], [2,undefined]
```

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't know Array.map. I'll try it.

Comment: even shorter `data.map( function( a , i ) { 
    data[i][1] = data[i+1] && data[i+1][1];
});`

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative answer** provided that

- a sample is [x, y]
- x is a sequence 0, 1, 2, ..., m (with no gaps), when you receive a new sample you would:

then

```
// push the value of the sample, not X, just Y
data[0].push(value)
// remove the first element from the array.
data[0].shift()
```

x is the index of the array.

---

Performance-wise, I wouldn't change the source array but the accessor function.

So you could have a class that provides the shifting when reading, e.g. a *ShiftedArray class*, where *channel is data[z]*:

```
var shifter = 0

function get(index) {
 return [channel[index][0], channel[index + this.shifter][1]];
}
```

then you could provide increase the shift:

```
function increase() {
  this.shifter++;
}
```

or decrease it:

```
function increase() {
  this.shifter--;
}
```

Then to access the array data:

```
var item1 = shiftedArray.get(0);
// shall return [0, 2]

shiftedArray.increase();
var item2 = shiftedArray.get(0);
// shall return [0, 4]
```

The above is just conceptual code, not tested, you should add boundaries checks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it doesn't work. The array is always fully populated. A new sample should be pushed at the end, popping the first value (only for the y values! otherwise it's very simple).

Comment: is x value a sequence 0, 1, 2, ..., m? are there any gaps in the sequence? PS: I fixed a bug the in sample 'get' function.

Comment: so, you don't need that, that's the index of the array and you can just shift/push elements. (x is untouched, so I assume it'll always be a sequence from 0 to m)

Comment: Ok, I got it now. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to split `data` on two separate arrays and use second array like [Circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: This was the first attempt. But the target function requires an array of points as described. Anyway, I'm trying other solutions to avoid this problem at all.